# How to properly perform a managed query?

Tags: android, android-cursor

I'm developing against API 11 so I don't think it's necessary to use `LoadCursor`.

I have three classes: `MainActivity extends Activity`, `Columns extends PagerAdapter`, and `GetMp3Tag`

**`MainActivity`**

```
miAdapter = new Columns ();
columnas = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.columnas);
columnas.setAdapter(miAdapter);
```

**`Columns`**

```
GetMP3Tag MP3TAG = new GetMP3Tag();
MP3TAG.GetCount(types_ID.ALL_ARTIST);
```

**`GetMp3Tag`**

```
public String GetCount(types_ID Type_First) {
    Cursor cursor;
    cursor = managedQuery(Path_Normal, STAR , audioselection, null, null);
}
```

**LogCat**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException at android.content.ContextWrapper.getContentResolver(ContextWrapper.java:99)
```

Comment: use getContentResolver().query in place of managedQuery(....).

Comment: Show the whole stack trace.

Comment: using getContentResolver().query i get same error